# How can I check if multiple strings exist in another string?

Tags: r

I have this string:

```
myStr <- "I am very beautiful btw"
str <- c("very","beauti","bt")
```

Now I want to check whether `myStr` includes all strings in `str`, how can I do this in R? For example above it should be `TRUE`.
Many Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can use `grepl` (not `grep`, actually), but you must run it once for each substring:

```
> sapply(str, grepl, myStr)
  very beauti     bt 
  TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
```

To get only one result if all of them are true, use `all`:

```
> all(sapply(str, grepl, myStr))
[1] TRUE
```

Edit:

In case you have more than one string to check, say:

```
myStrings <- c("I am very beautiful btw", "I am not beautiful btw")
```

You then run the `sapply` code, which will return a matrix with one row for each string in myStrings. Apply `all` on each row:

```
> apply(sapply(str, grepl, myStrings), 1, all)
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: thanks for your response @Molx how about if myStr includes more than one string and I want to see which of them include all the strings in str?

Comment: Without going to a matrix via `apply`, you could also do: `do.call(mapply, c(all,lapply(str, grepl, myStrings) ))`

Answer (score 5):

Using `stringr` you could do:

```
str_detect(myStr, str)
```

Which returns a result for each substring:

```
#[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Or as per @thelatemail suggestion, if you want to know if all of them are true:

```
all(str_detect(myStr,str))
```

Which gives:

```
#[1] TRUE
```

You could also find the location (start, end) of every character in `myStr` that matches `str`

```
str_locate(myStr, str)
```

Which gives:

```
#     start end
#[1,]     6   9
#[2,]    11  16
#[3,]    21  22
```

Comment: If you're going to use `stringr`, use the appropriate function - `all(str_detect(myStr,str))`

Comment: It also possible to use "any" instead of "all" if we need to have only one TRUE value - any(str_detect(myStr,str))