# Check whether string is contained within a list

Tags: r

I'm trying to find a way to check whether a list **contains an element that itself contains a particular string**. Finding an exact match is simple with `%in%`:

```
list1 <- list("a","b","c")
"a" %in% list1
[1] TRUE
```

But it only works if the element is identical, i.e. it doesn't return TRUE if the element only contains the string:

```
list2 <- list("a,b","c,d")
"a" %in% list2
[2] FALSE
```

Is there a way to generate TRUE for the second example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like `any(grepl("a", unlist(list2)))` ? Or if they are always comma separated then `"a" %in% unlist(strsplit(as.character(list2), ","))`

Comment: commenting on @ronak-shah 's answer, if every element in `list2` is just a simple character string, `unlist()` can be omitted. `any(grepl("a",list2))` should do.

Comment: I don't know anything about r.
But I did find this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180281/how-can-i-check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string

Comment: If you can use `c` instead of `list`, this question is simpler.

Answer (score 4):

Could you try flipping it around and using

```
library(data.table)
any(list2 %like% 'a')
```

The `any()` is included because without it the output is : `[1]  TRUE FALSE`

Comment: What package is `%like%` from? I haven't seen that one.

Comment: For some reason I thought it was a base function. But it isn't. It's in data.table

Comment: @Marius `%like%` is in `library(data.table)`

Answer (score 3):

```
library(stringi)

list2 <- list("a,b","c,d")

stri_detect_fixed(list2, "a")
## [1]  TRUE FALSE

stri_detect_fixed(list2, "b")
## [1]  TRUE FALSE

stri_detect_fixed(list2, "c")
## [1] FALSE  TRUE

stri_detect_fixed(list2, "d")
## [1] FALSE  TRUE

stri_detect_fixed(list2, "q")
## [1] FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

Without using an additional library.

```r
# You can get the index of the match with grep
grep('a', list2)

# You can get the TRUE/FALSE you wanted by checking the length
length(grep('a', list2)) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled across this as I had the same question - now found a solution that might work here as well using the `rlist` package:

This gives the matching list element:

```r
rlist::list.search(.data = list2, expr = grepl("a",.))
[[1]]
[1] "a,b"
```

And this gives the position:

```r
match(rlist::list.search(.data = list2, expr = grepl("a",.)),list2)
1
```

Which then works like this: `list2[[1]]`