# Matching the word pattern and replace the word by NA in R

Tags: r

I've 2 dataframes in R - one list of names and other one is a word dictionary. If any part a name is part of word dictionary then replace by NA else return the name

Names - Dataframe

```
Name
Louis
Messi
duplessis
Jegan
Praveen
```

word dictionary - Dataframe

```
Dictionary
vee
sis
```

Expected Output

```
Name        Processed_Name
Louis       Louis
Messi       Messi
duplessis   NA
Jegan       Jegan
Praveen     NA
```

Comment: What have you tried? Here is [a good start to test with grepl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128617/test-if-characters-in-string-in-r), and see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180281/how-can-i-check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(data.table) # needed library

# create data
dt <- data.table("Name"=c("Louis",
                          "Messi",
                          "duplessis",
                          "Jegan",
                          "Praveen"))
dict <- c("vee","sis")

# make a combined vector of the words in the dictionary
dict_2 <- paste0(dict,collapse = "|") 
# desired output
dt[,processed_Name:=ifelse(Name%like%dict_2,NA,Name)]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
        Name processed_Name
1:     Louis          Louis
2:     Messi          Messi
3: duplessis             NA
4:     Jegan          Jegan
5:   Praveen             NA
```

**UPDATE based on OP's comment**

```
  # changed the input a bit, so that it contains the numbers 
# that i am going to generate for the dictionary.
dt <- data.table("Name"=c("Loui1s",
                          "Messi",
                          "duple2ssis",
                          "Jegan",
                          "Praveen"))

dict_all <- as.character(c(1:5000)) # i generate numbers so that they all are different
dict_split <- split(dict_all, ceiling(seq_along(dict_all)/1000))
dict_split_2 <- lapply(dict_split, function(x){paste0(x, collapse = "|")})
dt[,processed_Name_2:=ifelse(Name%like%dict_split_2[[1]] | Name%like%dict_split_2[[2]] |
                               Name%like%dict_split_2[[3]] | Name%like%dict_split_2[[4]] |
                               Name%like%dict_split_2[[5]],NA,Name)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried this earlier.. it's not working as my dictionary has 5000 words and throwing error as invalid regular expression.

Comment: do you mean it throws an error when you paste them next to each other ?

Comment: When processing this line dt[,processed_Name:=ifelse(Name%like%dict_2,NA,Name)].. We get the error..

Comment: You can split the dictionary vector into parts. I tried with 5. Please see update

Comment: Thanks mate for your great input. it's working for small dataset. But it's taking more time big dataset.