# Filter a list that contain ALL of multiple partial strings in R

Tags: r, string, filter, grepl

I am trying to filter a list of file names, based on a set of keywords the user picked in a shiny app, and the final list should be only files that contain ALL partial keywords

I have been trying so far with this code:

```
sapply(filenames, grepl, keywords)
```

but how to get from that output to the ones that have all true. 
I tried this solution from this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180281/how-can-i-check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string),  but

```
all(sapply(filenames, grepl, keywords)
```

of course gives false for my list. I could write a list apply function to apply the `sapply(....)` to each element, but perhaps there is a more efficient way to achieve all at once?

I also looked at `grep` or `grepl` options, but they only take `OR` arguments, not `AND` it seems.

example keywords :

```
keywords <- c("Syn", "2017")
```

example list:

```
 filenames <- 
c("AdditionalListMode_M1bI Euk SWS 60 20 90 90 80 2016-06-18 13u22.csv",       "AdditionalListMode_M1bI Euk SWS 60 20 90 90 80 2016-06-19 13u26.csv",      
"AdditionalListMode_M1bI Euk SWS 60 20 90 90 80 2017-06-19 13u27.csv",       "AdditionalListMode_M1bI Euk SWS 60 20 90 90 80 2017-06-20 13u11.csv",      
"AdditionalListMode_M1bI Euk SWS 60 20 90 90 80 2018-06-21 13u12.csv",       "AdditionalListMode_M1bI Euk SWS 60 20 90 90 80 2018-06-22 16u00.csv",      
"AdditionalListMode_M1bI Large Euk SWS 50 20 90 90 80 2016-06-18 13u25.csv", "AdditionalListMode_M1bI Large Euk SWS 50 20 90 90 80 2016-06-19 13u29.csv",
"AdditionalListMode_M1bI Large Euk SWS 50 20 90 90 80 2017-06-20 13u14.csv", "AdditionalListMode_M1bI Large Euk SWS 50 20 90 90 80 2017-06-21 13u15.csv",
"AdditionalListMode_M1bI Large Euk SWS 50 20 90 90 80 2018-06-22 16u03.csv", "AdditionalListMode_M1bI Syn 60 90 90 110 2016-06-18 13u31.csv",            
"AdditionalListMode_M1bI Syn 60 90 90 110 2016-06-19 13u35.csv",             "AdditionalListMode_M1bI Syn 60 90 90 110 2017-06-20 13u20.csv",           
"AdditionalListMode_M1bI Syn 60 90 90 110 2017-06-21 13u21.csv",             "AdditionalListMode_M1bI Syn 60 90 90 110 2018-06-22 16u09.csv")
```

expected result:

```
"AdditionalListMode_M1bI Syn 60 90 90 110 2017-06-20 13u20.csv"           
"AdditionalListMode_M1bI Syn 60 90 90 110 2017-06-21 13u21.csv"
```

Apologies for possibly posting a slightly duplicate question but I was unable to find a real solution after a long search on SO and google

**EDIT ON RESULTS:**
I used a dataset of 359 file names to obtain microbenchmark results of all answers that worked (including the keyword order sensitive ones:

```
Unit: microseconds
                                                                                                                       expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq       max neval
 filesshort <- filenames[apply(sapply(keywords, function(x) grepl(x,      filenames)), 1, function(y) sum(y) == length(y))] 1220.588 1318.093 1691.7377 1366.2530 1635.477  5718.049    50
                               filesshort <- filenames[Reduce("&", lapply(keywords, function(x) grepl(x,      filenames)))]  532.922  568.055  640.7301  591.5435  637.137  1971.415    50
                                            filesshort <- grep(paste(keywords, collapse = ".*"), filenames,      value = T)  302.779  331.991  379.9144  343.4390  380.941   790.303    50
                             filesshort <- regmatches(filenames, regexpr(paste(keywords, collapse = ".*"),      filenames)) 2244.587 2310.905 2668.2153 2456.9655 2708.820  5758.314    50
                    filesshort <- unlist(regmatches(filenames, gregexpr(paste(keywords,      collapse = ".*"), filenames))) 3768.742 3985.463 5491.8536 4654.5750 5322.109 42538.964    50
```

equation 3 with grep was by far the fastest, but that one is also keyword order sensitive. 
equation 2 with reduce is the winner by a distance compared to the other 4 answers if we look at both speed, and tolerance to keyword order.

Comment: why downvote this legitimate question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
filenames[Reduce("&", lapply(keywords, function(x) grepl(x, filenames)))]
#[1] "AdditionalListMode_M1bI Syn 60 90 90 110 2017-06-20 13u20.csv"
#[2] "AdditionalListMode_M1bI Syn 60 90 90 110 2017-06-21 13u21.csv"
```

Comment: by far the fastest solution of the ones that are tolerant to keyword order

Answer (score 1):

```
filenames[apply(sapply(keywords, function(x) grepl(x, filenames)), 1, function(y) sum(y) == length(y))]
[1] "AdditionalListMode_M1bI Syn 60 90 90 110 2017-06-20 13u20.csv"
[2] "AdditionalListMode_M1bI Syn 60 90 90 110 2017-06-21 13u21.csv"
```

Comment: works well, but slower than the reduce solution of d.b. thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Np. Regardless of speed d.b. has a much more readable solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
keywords <- c("Syn.*2017")

> filenames[grep(keywords,filenames)]
[1] "AdditionalListMode_M1bI Syn 60 90 90 110 2017-06-20 13u20.csv"
[2] "AdditionalListMode_M1bI Syn 60 90 90 110 2017-06-21 13u21.csv"
```

Comment: Ok, works, but is keyword order sensitive. And the file names can contain the words in any order.

Answer (score 1):

```
 grep("Syn.*?2017",filenames,value = T)
[1] "AdditionalListMode_M1bI Syn 60 90 90 110 2017-06-20 13u20.csv"
[2] "AdditionalListMode_M1bI Syn 60 90 90 110 2017-06-21 13u21.csv"

regmatches(filenames,regexpr("(.*Syn).*?2017(.*)",filenames)))
[1] "AdditionalListMode_M1bI Syn 60 90 90 110 2017-06-20 13u20.csv"
[2] "AdditionalListMode_M1bI Syn 60 90 90 110 2017-06-21 13u21.csv"

unlist(regmatches(filenames,gregexpr("(.*Syn).*?2017(.*)",filenames)))
[1] "AdditionalListMode_M1bI Syn 60 90 90 110 2017-06-20 13u20.csv"
[2] "AdditionalListMode_M1bI Syn 60 90 90 110 2017-06-21 13u21.csv"
```

You can use any that suites the job at hand.

Comment: Testing all answers now for speed. Your options all have the same problem: The order of the keywords becomes a success or fail issue

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by that?

Comment: Keywords <- c("Syn", "2018") gives 2 results with your code,  Keywords <- c("2018", " Syn") gives zero. It should work regardless of in what order the user enters the keywords in the inputfield of my shiny app that reads out the entry into the keyword string

Comment: ohh. I hear what you mean. well that can be fixed, although will take in a further `paste0` function