# tidyverse/dplyr solution for str_detect case/mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

I have seen snippets of this floating around but sadly no full answers as of yet so thought I would ask.

I'm working on a function to assign a value based off the presence or absence of some key words ranked by severity. Like such:

`severity <- c("kw1", "kw2", "kw3", "kw4", "kw5", "kw6")`

Where it basically goes through a single column in a dataset and assigns a value based on the presence or absence of the **first/most** severe entry in the severity list.

Using the following, I realized you could detect multiple strings with `str_detect`:

[How can I check if multiple strings exist in another string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180281/how-can-i-check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string)

```
severity_rankings <- severity_df |>
  dplyr::mutate(
    # Classify severity based on strings
    severity_kw = dplyr::case_when(
      if (any(stringr::str_detect(tolower(severity_string),severity))) ~ severity[min(which(str_detect(tolower(severity_string),severity) == TRUE))],
      .default = NA
    ))
```

But this keeps throwing an error like it's trying to parse the whole column:

```
Error in `dplyr::mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `severity_kw = dplyr::case_when(...)`.
Caused by error in `stringr::str_detect()`:
! Can't recycle `string` (size 20) to match `pattern` (size 6).
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Ultimately, what I would like is an output along these lines:

```
ID          severity_string severity_kw
1     kw1 with KW2 and kw6         kw1
2                      kw6         kw6
3   kw6 with kW5, kw2 also         kw2
4                      KW3         kw3
5                      KW5         kw5
6   KW4 with kw2, kw1 also         kw1
7                      KW1         kw1
8                      KW2         kw2
9             KW4 with KW5         kw4
10                      KW6         kw6
11 KW6 with KW1 on the side         kw1
12     KW2 with KW4 and KW1         kw1
13             kw5 with kw6         kw5
14                      kw7        <NA>
15              KW3 and KW2         kw2
16                      KW2         kw2
17              KW1 and KW6         kw1
18                      KW3         kw3
19              KW3 and KW1         kw1
20                      kw1         kw1
```

I'm sure it's bad syntax or the wrong `dplyr` call on my part, but not sure where to start.
Any and all advice would be appreciated.

For generating the initial dataframe:

```
severity_df <- data.frame(
    ID = c(1:20), 
    severity_string = c("kw1 with KW2 and kw6", "kw6", "kw6 with kW5, kw2 also", "KW3", "KW5",
                        "KW4 with kw2, kw1 also", "KW1", "KW2", "KW4 with KW5", "KW6",
                        "KW6 with KW1 on the side", "KW2 with KW4 and KW1", "kw5 with kw6", "kw7", "KW3 and KW2",
                        "KW2", "KW1 and KW6", "KW3", "KW3 and KW1", "kw1"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're trying to use `str_detect()` with values for `string` and `input` which have incompatible lengths. You can reproduce the error like this:

```r
str_detect(c("foo", "bar"), c("foo", "bar", "baz"))
#> Error in `str_detect()`:
#> ! Can't recycle `string` (size 2) to match `pattern` (size 3).
#> Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I think you've got a misplaced `if` in there too, but that seems to be besides the point of the question.

For your use case, I would change tack and use a tool like `map_chr()` with a bespoke function:

```r
severity_df |>
  mutate(
    severity_kw = severity_string |>

      # For each value of severity_string...
      purrr::map_chr(function(x) {
        
        # For each value of severity...
        for (pattern in severity) {
          
          # Return the value of severity, if there's a match
          if (str_detect(x, regex(pattern, ignore_case = TRUE))) {
            return(pattern)
          }
        }
        
        # If no values match, return NA
        NA_character_
      })
  )
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it with sapply or lapply and skip the loop?

Comment: You should be able to swap `purrr::map_chr()` for `sapply()` without issues. This is just as loopy as the purrr approach though

Comment: The `for` loop is used for both clarity and performance purposes, so I'm reluctant to rewrite it without a good reason.

Comment: Okay this goes beyond my initial question, but if it by any chance DID detect more than one of the strings and I wanted to assign them their own class, is there a call I could to `case_when` or `mutate` for what to do there?

Comment: You'd probably want the result to have potentially more than one row for each row in the original data frame, so you'd likely want `reframe()`

Comment: E.g:
``` r
severity_df |>
  rowwise() |>
  reframe(
    pick(everything()),
    category = str_extract_all(severity_string, regex(severity, ignore_case = TRUE))
  ) |>
  unnest(category)
```

Comment: An issue with substituting `map_chr()` for `for` is that it is less obvious how one would break out of the loop as soon as a match is discovered (the loss of efficiency incurred by checking all values might not be important, though)